# Swift : Clear UITableView Cells

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I have an variable to store objects of a custom Class which I've loaded into a UITableView.

I'm giving the user an option to clear everything out. When this runs I'm clearing the array that stores all the players but how do I clear the TableView?

I've tried tableView.reloadData() but it doesn't do anything.

Custom Class & Global Variable:

```
var players: [AnyObject] = []
Class Player{
    var playerName: String?

    init(name:String){
        playerName = name
    }
}
```

Custom Cell cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell: CustomMainCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CustomMainCell") as CustomMainCell
    // Get Player
        let thisPlayer:Player = players[indexPath.row] as Player

        cell.nameLabel?.text = thisPlayer.playerName
    }

    return cell
}
```

Settings Clear Function:

```
alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Clear Players?", style: .Default, handler: { (action: UIAlertAction!) in
            players.removeAll()
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }))
```

Comment: Is the calling of `tableView.reloadData()` being executed on the main thread/queue?

Comment: Reloading the data should work if your array is empty at the time you call it. You should show the code you're using.

Comment: Edit your question to show the appropriate code. Have you also used the debugger to step through the code and confirm the array is empty ?

Comment: If I println(players) after the removeAll it shows []

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Clearing the array **before** calling `tableView.reloadData()` should work.

I assume your `numberOfRowsInSection:` and `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` are also using the array data to return the correct values/objects.

Comment: This was the issue. I was using a different variable to keep track of the number of players.... **THANKS!**